# How to find out IP address held by a Windows DHCP client yesterday?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ip, dhcp, dhcp-server

We have a Windows Server 2008 with DHCP server running. 
I can see the current leases and reservations, is there a way to see the status of yesterday (or at least what IP a particular client had yesterday).
I know the odds are it would be the same IP address but given that the client is a laptop and lease time is 4hours...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have DHCP Audit logging enabled you might have the data in the logs.

Details on how to set up [DHCP Audit Log on Windows Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759178.aspx) including the event types (e.g IP address lease etc)

By default the log files would be located in

> %windir%\System32\Dhcp.